# Jquery How to change the value of three "div"that have the same class

Tags: jquery

please I have the following markup :

```
<div class="item"> 1 a </div>
<div class="item"> 2 b </div>
<div class="item"> 3 c </div>
```

After a click on a button, I want to increase using jQuery the value of the three elements by 2 and get :

```
<div class="item"> 3 a </div>
<div class="item"> 4 b </div>
<div class="item"> 5 c </div>
```

Please any help ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do this in your button's event handler :

```
$('.item').each(function(){
   $(this).html(
      $(this).html().replace(/(\d+)/, function(v){return parseInt(v,10)+1})
   );
});
```

This increments the first number in your items (if you want to increment any number, just change the regex to `/(\d+)/g`).

**[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/X38Aw/)**

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your html like this:

```
<div class="item"> <span>1</span> product </div>
<div class="item"> <span>2</span> product </div>
```

And the your Javascript should be:

```
$('.yourbutton').click(function(){
    $( '.item' ).each(function(){
        var actual = parseInt( $(this).find( 'span' ).html() );
        $(this).find( 'span' ).html( actual + 1 );
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the .appendTo class [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

> With .appendTo(), on the other hand, the content precedes the method,
>   either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and
>   it is inserted into the target container.

Comment: How does this answer the question?